# Print front page on a single piece of paper without adding empty pages to PDF

Tags: pdf, printing

Some people use empty pages to make sure that the front page gets printed on a single piece of paper ([example](http://mitschriebwiki.nomeata.de/Ana1.pdf)).

I think this is a bad solution, as some people might want to print every page on a new piece of paper. They will get some empty pieces of paper. It is also bad for people who read the document in a PDF-reader.

Is there another possibility to make sure that the front page (or other pages) get printed on a new piece of paper without adding an empty piece of paper?

Comment: That looks more like the settings used ensure that new sectional divisions at the 'chapter' level (so, including things like the table of contents) start on a 'recto' or odd-numbered page.  Usually, you can use an option like `openany` in your `\documentclass` declaration to change this behaviour. E.g., in the `book` class, `openany` will start a chapter on a new page, regardless of whether it is even or odd; without this option, it will start them only on an odd-numbered page.

Comment: FWIW, I always offer my clients two builds, one with `twoside`, and one with `oneside`. Either is right for hard copy, depending on how they want to print it. On the other hand, PDF isn't all that friendly for non-paper reading; `oneside` is better for this, as the pages don't change shape as you turn them.

Comment: The source is also available: http://mitschriebwiki.nomeata.de/data/Ana1.tex - So the empty pages are a result of `twoside` and there is no better way than offering one document with `twoside` and one with `oneside`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the highest level here, you have only two options: `oneside` or `twoside`.

- Avoid inserting blank pages manually; use \cleardoublepage if needed.
  (`memoir` has    `\cleartorecto` and `\cleartoverso`.)
- If you're going to print on just one side of the paper, use    `oneside`
- If you're going to print on two sides of the paper, use `twoside`
- Using `twoside`, other options such as `openany` can reduce the    number of blank pages
- PDFs are pretty awful for screen reading, but if you're going to    do that, then use `oneside`, since the layout stays the same 'shape'    when you turn from even to odd pages and vice versa.

Oh, and if it's not 'you', then ask your audience and offer them both options.